# Query rows Depending on StartDate and EndDate

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to retrieve the WeekIDs between the given Start Date and End Date

For example, 
StartDate = 2014-01-20
EndDate = 2014-02-20

So, the result should be... 201404, 201405, 201406, 201407, 201408

[image]

I tried to run the query like the following, but it returns blank.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '20140120'
SET @EndDate = '20140220'

SELECT 
    WeekID
FROM
    dbo.DimWeeks
WHERE
    (@StartDate >= FirstDayOfTheWeek 
    AND @EndDate <= LastDayOfTheWeek)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query works correct, you are getting no records because there is no row with `FirstDayOfTheWeek <= 20140120` and `LastDayOfTheWeek >= 20140220`.

Maybe you wanted this instead:

```
WHERE
    ( FirstDayOfTheWeek >= @StartDate
 AND  LastDayOfTheWeek  <= @EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
where @StartDate <= LastDayOfTheWeek and
      @EndDate >= FirstDayOfTheWeek
```

Two intervals overlap when one starts before the other ends and the first ends after the other starts.